# xPad-like app for Windows

Tags: notepad

I like to keep notes simple. I have a ton of .txt files littering my desktop.
I'd love to find an app like http://getxpad.com/ (Mac Only) for the PC.
Evernote/OneNote are overkill.

Ideally I'd love to find an powerful notepad app where I can keep the notes in a sidebar and have the main window for the note content.

Does such a beast exist?

Comment: OneNote is not overkill, it does exactly what you need, and much more.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything that matches all your requirements off the top of my head.  Have you checked out http://www.osalt.com/onenote ?

One tactic I've adopted is to use a [Google Doc](http://docs.google.com) for all my "scraps" that I would normally litter about my desk on Post-Its.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "Notecase", which exists for Windows, Linux and OS-X. Data is fully interchangeable.
The tree on the left (titles) is hierarchical. Too many levels complicate things.

Comment: Please provide a link to the software you mention.